# How do I perform a twitter search using advanced parameters

Tags: java, twitter4j

http://twitter.com/search-advanced

I would like to perform search queries which mimic the above screen 
(e.g. How do I find all tweets which satisfy "none of the words" 
criteria or just #hashtags criteria). Would it be possible to mix-n- 
match some of these fields using twitter4j, currently I am able to 
perform only simple searches using keywords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you fill out some of the advanced search page and actually do the search, it'll populate a search box with the constructed query string.  For example, if I set it up as follows:

- All of these words: word1 word2
- Any of these words: word3 word4
- None of these words: word5
- From these accounts: user1 user2
- Mentioning these accounts: user3

"word1 word2 word3 OR word4 -word5 from:user1 OR from:user2 @user3"

Then you just stick that string into your created query.

```
Query query = new Query("word1 word2 word3 OR word4 -word5 from:user1 OR from:user2 @user3");
```